# Apace Beam's FileIO.Match step is stuck in the Dataflow job while matching a large number of files from GCS

Tags: file-io, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm building a streaming pipeline to process the log files stored in a GCS bucket and insert into BigQuery using the Dataflow streaming job. Pipeline just works fine when there are only a few 100 files that match the pattern.

However, in production we have about 2.5 million files(each file can be a max 20 MB in size) and the dataflow step that matches the given file pattern is just stuck  and I do not see any output to further steps down the pipeline. System lag for this step keeps increasing and I also see the memory consumption in the worker node keeps increasing with cpu usage coming down.

My code is as follows

```
pipeline
        .apply(
            "Monitor new files",
            FileIO.match()
                .filepattern("gs://" + options.getBucketPathToMonitor() + "/**.gz")
                .continuously(
                    Duration.standardMinutes(1),
                    Watch.Growth.afterTimeSinceNewOutput(
                        Duration.standardMinutes(
                            10))))
        .apply("Read file names", FileIO.readMatches().withCompression(Compression.AUTO))
        .apply("Read JSON files", TextIO.readFiles());
```

I have also tried TextIO.read + withHintMatchesManyFiles but I see the same behaviour. I can also confirm from the logs that the match file pattern I'm giving is right as I see the number of files matched in the logs.

My assumption is Apache beam is supposed to work with huge data and maybe I'm doing something wrong. Can you please help me figure out the issue here or help me with any suggestions to overcome the issue?

Comment: I think the `FileIO` with `continuously` is not adapted and performant with a huge amount of file and data. Can you use a batch pipeline instead with TextIO or FileIO ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the log files are stored in sub-folders (daywise) in the GCS storage bucket. So, I managed to create file matching patterns for sub-folders in a DoFn that outputs a PCollection of Strings (File matching strings) which is then transformed in the next step by FileIO.matchAll() transform. In this case multiple threads process each file pattern and I was able to process all the 2.5 million files comfortably.